# Call function in flutter on newer version sdk

Tags: flutter, dart

Below example work fine on flutter app where is sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"  and shared_preferences: ^2.0.6.

After create new project SDK default is sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0" and shared_preferences: ^2.0.7 version shared_preferences: ^2.0.6 not working on sdk 2.12

After call signIn nothing happened on old project login work fine. Any solution?

```
signIn(String email, String password, BuildContext context) async {

  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var jsonResponse = null;
  var response = await http.get(Uri.https('myrl', 'login' + '$email/$password'));

 
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
    if (jsonResponse != null) {
      sharedPreferences.setString("email_token", email);

      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => MyApp()
       ));
    }
  } else {
    txtPassword.clear();
  }
}
```

NOTE

**On emulator work but after build apk and run on mobile devices after click on login button and call signIn don't get anything.**

EDIT

After add in AndroidManifest.xml below permission work fine.

**android.permission.INTERNET**

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not cleared on your question. What is "nothing happened"?

After quick read your code, if "nothing happened" is nothing happened on login page (not go to other page and password field not cleared), only happen when jsonResponse = null

Comment: On emulator work but after build apk and run on mobile devices after click on login button and call signIn don't get anything.